# pytezos deploy kt

Tags: smart-contracts

I'm following the https://baking-bad.github.io/pytezos/#originate-contract refs to originate a contract. I suspect that it has something to do with how I usually iniatialize the storage, so if anyone can help me with that I would be really greatful, I'm digging it forever.

While trying to deploy I get the following error:

Michelson error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-47-c91371e05a4c>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('~/testpytezos.py', wdir='~')

  File "~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder_kernels/customize/spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder_kernels/customize/spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "~/testpytezos.py", line 33, in <module>
    op = pytezos.origination(script=contract.script()).autofill().sign().inject()

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pytezos/operation/group.py", line 171, in autofill
    raise RpcError.from_errors(OperationResult.errors(opg_with_metadata)) from None

MichelsonRuntimeError: ({'id': 'proto.005-PsBabyM1.michelson_v1.unexpected_annotation',
  'kind': 'permanent',
  'location': 8},)
```

Micheline error:

```
  File "/home/crzy/Documents/hicetnunc/tezos-storage-flask/testpytezos.py", line 30, in <module>
    contract = Contract.from_file('./smart_contracts/transaction_micheline.tz')

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pytezos/michelson/contract.py", line 306, in from_file
    return cls.from_michelson(f.read())

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pytezos/michelson/contract.py", line 296, in from_michelson
    return cls(michelson_to_micheline(text))

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pytezos/michelson/micheline.py", line 493, in michelson_to_micheline
    return michelson_parser().parse(data)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pytezos/michelson/grammar.py", line 163, in parse
    return self.parser.parse(code)

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ply/yacc.py", line 333, in parse
    return self.parseopt_notrack(input, lexer, debug, tracking, tokenfunc)

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ply/yacc.py", line 1201, in parseopt_notrack
    tok = call_errorfunc(self.errorfunc, errtoken, self)

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ply/yacc.py", line 192, in call_errorfunc
    r = errorfunc(token)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pytezos/michelson/grammar.py", line 152, in p_error
    raise MichelsonParserError(p)

MichelsonParserError: LexToken([,'[',1,0)
```

context:

python code:

```
with open('./faucets/tz1WGhT231BgqK7CrjbMB5xDsbdDSBJZiw5E.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)

pytezos = pytezos.using(
        key='./faucets/tz1WGhT231BgqK7CrjbMB5xDsbdDSBJZiw5E.json',
        shell='babylonnet')

r = requests.post('http://hicetnunc.glitch.me/api/reveal', json=data)
print (r.json().get('privateKey'))

pytezos.using(key=r.json().get('privateKey'))

contract = Contract.from_file('./smart_contracts/transaction.tz')
print(contract.script)

op = pytezos.origination(script=contract.script()).autofill().sign().inject()
```

Michelson smartcontract code:

```
parameter (or (or (nat %divisor) (unit %double)) (nat %value));

storage (nat %storedValue);

code
  {
    DUP;
    CDR;
    SWAP;
    CAR;
    IF_LEFT
      {
        IF_LEFT
          {
            PAIR;
            DUP;
            CAR;
            PUSH nat 5;
            SWAP;
            COMPARE;
            GT;
            IF
              {
              }
              {
                PUSH string "WrongCondition: params.divisor > 5";
                FAILWITH;
              };
            DUP;
            CDR;
            DUUP;
            CAR;
            EDIV;
            IF_SOME
              {
                CAR;
              }
              {
                PUSH string "division by zero";
                FAILWITH;
              };
            SWAP;
            DROP;
            NIL operation;
            PAIR;
          }
          {
            PAIR;
            DUP;
            CDR;
            PUSH nat 2;
            MUL;
            SWAP;
            DROP;
            NIL operation;
            PAIR;
          };
      }
      {
        PAIR;
        DUP;
        CAR;
        SWAP;
        DROP;
        NIL operation;
        PAIR;
      };
  }
```

Comment: 1) the smartpy contract you point to has nothing to do with the michelson you put in your question so please ask one question per distinct issue 2) your smartpy contract hardcodes nonsensical tezos address as constants in the storage so it is not expected to be deployable.

Comment: It would be useful to have the initial SmartPy script and the version used.

Comment: @Ezy indeed, the michelson I posted was not related to the smartpy code I provided, I'm sorry about that. The code on smartpy ui did compile without any edits actually. Thanks for the caution and attention you all.

Comment: @FFF It's the pretifier example, actually.

Comment: The prettifier example has been cooked up by hand by removing some random parts of an actual generated contract. It's not a real example and I didn't know anyone tried to originate it.

Comment: everyone just hails metadata

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with the storage annotation (%storedValue), if you remove it, everything works.
In the storage section, field annotations (starting with %) are allowed in components of pair types, option types and or types.

Answer (score 1):

As Michael points out, in this case the problem was due to a malformed contract, and thus has nothing to do with tezospy. A tips is to first verify that your contract typechecks, using [try-michelson](http://try-michelson.tzalpha.net/) for instance.